# MySQL Client Library version compatibility with Server?

Tags: c++, mysql, libmysql

We are wrting a C++ application which links to MySQL shared Library dynamically to communicate with Server. My question is for normal queries and stuff (which is supported by almost every library) , Is it necessary to enforce the Server and Library versions to be same ?

Note: There is mysql-shared-compat RPM which solves this issue but it contains all the libraries from previous releases. And we dont want to ask the user to install that package along with mysql-shared package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this discusson, HTH: http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/210702

Our client-server protocol has not changed much, if at all, in a long 
while. You should be quite safe using a 5.x-based client library to talk 
to a 4.1 and even a 3.x server.